# How to feed hour and minute data into chartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs, visualization

I'm trying to make a line chart using Chart.js. My data is of the form:

```
var result = [
  { x: "18:00", y: "230" },
  { x: "19:00", y: "232" },
  { x: "20:00", y: "236" },
  { x: "22:00", y: "228" }
];
```

Where x represents the time with hours and minutes. I fed the data like this

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00","24:00"],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Voltage Fluctuation',
                data: result,
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    unit: 'minute',
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'HH:mm'
          }
        }
      }],
    },
  }
});
```

And I'm getting an empty chart. Where am I going wrong? I feel I'm doing something wrong with my labels since they don't show up on the chart but I don't understand how. Is there any way I can feed datalabels with momentjs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot just pass the `result` array to `data`, as it isn't in correct format. `data` property expects an array of numbers. So, you need to parse the labels *(using moment.js)* and data from `result` array before using them for the chart.

Here is how labels and data should be parsed from the `result` array and fed to the chart :

```js
var result = [{ x: "18:00", y: "230" }, { x: "19:00", y: "232" }, { x: "20:00", y: "236" }, { x: "22:00", y: "228" }];

// parse labels and data
var labels = result.map(e => moment(e.x, 'HH:mm'));
var data = result.map(e => +e.y);

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Voltage Fluctuation',
         data: data,
         borderWidth: 1
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
               unit: 'hour',
               displayFormats: {
                  hour: 'HH:mm'
               }
            }
         }]
      },
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to make this only line? Instead of the area that the chart is occupying?

Comment: Yes, set `fill: false` for your dataset

Comment: Thanks once again