# hh:mm in chart.js on X-axis and text labels on the Y-axis

Tags: chart.js, momentjs

I want to show duration time in a horizontal bar chart. I found out that I need moment.js so the format hh:mm can be used but I cant get the horizontalbar to work. I ve tried to copy the code from [How to feed hour and minute data into chartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022383/how-to-feed-hour-and-minute-data-into-chartjs) and change it to how I want it but that doesn't work.

Code:

```
var result = [{ x: "150:00", y: "bar 1" }, { x: "19:00", y: "bar 2" }, { x: "20:00", y: "bar 3" }, { x: "22:00", y: "bar 4" }];

    // parse labels and data
    var labels = result.map(e => moment(e.x, 'HH:mm'));
    var data = result.map(e => +e.y);

    var ctx = document.getElementById("MeSeStatusCanvas").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Voltage Fluctuation',
                data: data,
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'hour',
                        displayFormats: {
                            hour: 'HH:mm'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    });
```

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

parse the labels and data as follows :

```
var labels = result.map(e => e.y);
var data = result.map(e => moment(e.x, 'HH:mm'));
```

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

use **`yLabels`** property instead of `labels` *(inside `data` object)*, as such :

```
...
data: {
      yLabels: labels,
      ...
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var result = [{ x: "150:00", y: "bar 1" }, { x: "19:00", y: "bar 2" }, { x: "20:00", y: "bar 3" }, { x: "22:00", y: "bar 4" }];

// parse labels and data
var labels = result.map(e => e.y);
var data = result.map(e => moment(e.x, 'HH:mm'));

var ctx = document.getElementById("MeSeStatusCanvas").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
      yLabels: labels,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Voltage Fluctuation',
         data: data,
         borderWidth: 1
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
               unit: 'hour',
               displayFormats: {
                  hour: 'HH:mm'
               },
               /* (required to show first bar)
                set min prop, less than the minimum value of data.
                in this case minimum data value is '15:00', so we set '14:00'
                */
               min: moment('14:00', 'HH:mm')
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="MeSeStatusCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ah yea, this is what I was looking for. Only now I noticed there is one other problem... The time axis must represent duration and not time. I noticed it is not possible to enter more time than 24hr. Do you know if there is a way to make this work?

Comment: NO! That's not possible. What you're seeing is the expected behavior.