# duration on horizontalbar with chartjs

Tags: charts, chart.js

For a couple of days I have been trying to get my chart working like I want it to work.

What I want is:

I want to create a horizontalbar chart with on x-axis duration **(not time)** in hh:mm format. On the y-axis I want the activity of the bars.

Two days ago I asked this question [hh:mm in chart.js on X-axis and text labels on the Y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299863/hhmm-in-chart-js-on-x-axis-and-text-labels-on-the-y-axis]) with the use of moment.js because I hoped that would do the trick, but it didn't...

Does anybody know if its possible and how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance